# UIView animations do not work when a delayed animation is added

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to move a `UILabel` twice but I'm getting strange behaviour. Here was my first animation:

```
- (IBAction)doAnimation:(id)sender
{
    CGRect labelFrame = self.label.frame;
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake((random() / (float)RAND_MAX) * self.view.frame.size.width,
                                 (random() / (float)RAND_MAX) * self.view.frame.size.height,
                                 labelFrame.size.width,
                                 labelFrame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                          delay:0
                        options:0
                     animations:^{
                         self.label.frame = newFrame;
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
}
```

This works perfectly. The label fades in while moving into place.

I then added a second delayed animation by adding this code at the end of `doAnimation:`

```
    CGRect newFrame2 = CGRectMake((random() / (float)RAND_MAX) * self.view.frame.size.width,
                          (random() / (float)RAND_MAX) * self.view.frame.size.height,
                          labelFrame.size.width,
                          labelFrame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                          delay:3
                        options:0
                     animations:^{
                         self.label.frame = newFrame2;
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
```

In this case, I get a different behaviour. The label jumps to the end of the first animation, waits the delay out, then animates the second move.

Out of curiosity, I tried animating two properties in animation 1.

```
animations:^{
                 self.label.frame = newFrame;
                 self.label.alpha = 1.0f;
             }
```

The alpha animates correctly, but the frame change doesn't.

If I add an alpha change in animation 2, then the alpha doesn't animate in animation 1 (instead just jumps to the end).

Is it possible to create an animation sequence on similar properties using delayed animations? I need to extend this to an arbitrary number of animations, depending on user inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this. Here it is.

I added an array to save an arbitrary number of coordinates to point to.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* animationCoordinates;
```

I then add views to the array before launching the animation sequence.

I also added a method to launch the next animation.

```
- (void)playNextAnimation
{
    if (self.animationCoordinates.count > 0)
    {
        CGPoint point = [[self.animationCoordinates objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
        CGRect labelFrame = self.label.frame;
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(point.x,
                                     point.y,
                                     self.originalHandFrame.size.width,
                                     self.originalHandFrame.size.height);
        [self animateWithDuration:2.0
                            delay:0.0
                       animations:^{
                           self.label.frame = newFrame;
                           self.label.alpha = 1.0f;
                       }
                       completion:^(BOOL success){
                           [self playNextAnimation];
                       }];
        [self.buttonsToAnimate removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

When I want to start my animations, I just call

```
[self playNextAnimation];
```

This plays the animations in sequence until all points have been visited.

Answer (score 0):

performing this animation is an asynchronous thing, i.e., the command for animating is given, and the program flow continues.
Also, if animation command is given for a view when the previous command has not completed, the previous command is completed without any animation and the new animation is performed.

I think you should put the second animation code in the completion block of the first animation, for which you are passing NULL currently. `completion` gets executed AFTER the animation has been performed, and at that point you wish to start your second animation I think.

Comment: The previous command IS animated, as you can see when I add the alpha animation. It's just not animated if the second animation affects the same property. Also, as I said, I need to be able to chain an arbitrary number of animations, depending on user input. I can't hardcore the sequence in the completion block.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what exactly you wish to do? What is the user input, and what should be the corresponding outcome?

Comment: The user will be touching an arbitrary number of areas. After submitting their answer, a hand will appear to point out the areas they missed of the ones they chose that don't apply. I have a solution, now. I'll be posting it today.